# Change(?) user input character into another character c language

Tags: c

Writing a program for school to cause a user inputted character to identify a gas cylinder. Here is what i have written so far, but all inputs display ammonia.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char n;

printf("Please enter the first letter of color of gas cylinder\n");
    scanf("%c", &n);

if(n = 'o' ){
    printf("Ammonia\n");
}
else if(n = 'b'){
    printf("Carbon Monoxide\n");
}
else if(n = 'y'){
    printf("Hydrogen\n");
}
else if(n = 'g'){
    printf("Oxygen\n");
}
else{
    printf("Contents Unknown\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Learn the difference between assignment (`=`) and comparison (`==`)

Comment: You should also learn early on how to properly format your code.  This will be a good start: http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `==`—the equality operator—inside your `if` statements.

`=` is the assignment operator—it will set `n` to be 'o', so your first `if` statement always returns true ('o' is non-zero).